# Finding the mismatch column names

Tags: oracle

I have two datasets, both having same column names and just one row. I want to display the column names for which there is a mismatch of column values. Could anyone please suggest how this can be done.

- Tables def: (id , name, age)
- Table 1 :  (1,"Aron",23)
- Table 2 :  (1,"Aron",21)

output : age

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the database system you're using.

Comment: I am trying to write plsql statement to get above result. I need to use this query in spark jobs.

Comment: Do you know what the column names are in advance?

Comment: Yes the column names are known in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could do both a union of the tables and an intersection of the tables and then get the difference between these.

```
create table table1 as (select 1 id, 'Aron' name, 23 age from dual);
insert into table1 values (2,'Bary',30);
create table table2 as (select 1 id, 'Aron' name, 21 age from dual);
insert into table2 values (2,'Bary',30);

(
select * from table1
union
select * from table2
)
minus 
(
select * from table1
intersect 
select * from table2
);
```

Here are some other ways it could be derived:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 
WHERE (id, name, age) not in (select id, name, age from table2)
   union all  
SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE (id, name, age) not in (select id, name, age from table1); 


SELECT * FROM table1 t1
WHERE not exists (
   select 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t1.name=t2.name AND t1.age=t2.age)
   union all  
SELECT * FROM table2 t2
WHERE not exists (
   select 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.id=t2.id AND t1.name=t2.name AND t1.age=t2.age); 


SELECT id, name, age, count(*) FROM (
   SELECT id, name, age FROM Table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, name, age FROM Table2
)
GROUP BY id, name, age
HAVING count(*) =1;
```